# javascript - compare dates in different formats

Tags: javascript, date

I have 2 dates which I need to compare to see if one is greater than the other but they are in different formats and I'm not sure of the best way to compare the 2.

The formats are:

`1381308375118` (this is var futureDate)

which is created by

`var today = new Date(); today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); var futureDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() + 56); //56 days in the future...`

And the other format is

`2013/08/26`

Any ideas how I can compare the 2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without using a 3rd party library, you can create new `Date` objects using both those formats, retrieve the number of milliseconds (since midnight Jan 1, 1970) using `getTime()`  and then simply use `>`:

```
new Date("2013/08/26").getTime() > new Date(1381308375118).getTime()
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I've only test in FF and IE9, but it seems like a valid way to compare dates, unless I've missed something.

Comment: You are comparing Date objects not the actual dates

Comment: Ahh ok. Modified to retrieve the millisecond value for each date.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend using [datejs library](http://www.datejs.com/).

Thus this can be written in one single line:

```
Date.today().isAfter(Date.parse('2013/08/26'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that I am comparing the "date" element of each format and exclude any "time" element. Then with both dates converted to milliseconds, simply compare the values. You could do something like this. If dates are equal it returns 0, if the first date is less that the second then return -1, otherwise return 1.

Javascript

```
function compareDates(milliSeconds, dateString) {
    var year,
        month,
        day,
        tempDate1,
        tempDate2,
        parts;

    tempDate1 = new Date(milliSeconds);
    year = tempDate1.getFullYear();
    month =  tempDate1.getDate();
    day = tempDate1.getDay();
    tempDate1 = new Date(year, month, day).getTime();

    parts = dateString.split("/");
    tempDate2 = new Date(parts[0], parts[1] - 1, parts[2]).getTime();

    if (tempDate1 === tempDate2) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (tempDate1 < tempDate2) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}

var format1 = 1381308375118,
    format2 = "2013/08/26";

console.log(compareDates(format1, format2));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/trL7e/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `Date.parse("2013/08/26")` and compare with former one

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to compare dates**

Each of your date must to passed through `Date` object i.e. `new Date(yourDate)`.
Now dates will have same format and these will be comparable

```js
let date1 = new Date()

let date2 = "Jan 1, 2019"

console.log(`Date 1: ${date1}`)
console.log(`Date 2: ${date2}`)

let first_date = new Date(date1)
let second_date = new Date(date2)

// pass each of the date to 'new Date(yourDate)'
// and get the similar format dates

console.log(`first Date: ${first_date}`)
console.log(`second Date: ${second_date}`)

// now these dates are comparable

if(first_date > second_date) {
  console.log(`${date2} has been passed`)
}
```