# Javascript compare 2 differently foramtted dates

Tags: javascript

So I have a date being pulled from a database called `preCountDate`

for this example `preCountDate = 2017-10-12`

I need to check if this is bigger than todays date which I am setting like this `preToday = new Date();` now I can see that they are returning different formats which I assume to the issue and why this isn't working:

```
if(preCountDate > preToday){
    preToday = [preCountDate, preCountDate = preToday][0];
    preCountDate = moment(preCountDate).subtract(1, 'day');
}
```

I use the above to check is the preCountDate is bigger, if yes then swap them around.

This doesn't get run with the above. I think its to do with the format that `preToday` returns but not sure how to format in a way that will work

help appreciated

Different to the one suggested as I am not using unix time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - compare dates in different formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227099/javascript-compare-dates-in-different-formats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
preCountDate = new Date(preCountDate); // this sorts out the format problem
if (preCountDate > preToday){
    // whatever you want to do with the dates here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using moment you could try this:

```
var preCountDate = moment("2017-10-12");
var preToday = moment();

if (preCountDate > preToday) {
   // do your thing...
}
```

or

```
if (preCountDate.isAfter(preCountDate)) {
   // do your thing...
}
```

or

```
if (preCountDate.diff(preCountDate) > 0) {
   // do your thing...
}
```

Comment: This is probably a better answer than mine

Comment: There is no better answer than other... there are just different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: That's very gracious. But given that the OP was using moment anyway, it does make a bit more sense to use moment throughout. Either way, at least he's got it working now.